# Search bar Autocomplete from API

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a book search bar with autocomplete that will show relevant results dynamically with each keypress. Everything is working and I'm getting the data, but results are not showing on the dropdown menu

Using angular 8 and Material 8.2.3

I'm trying to create a book search bar with autocomplete that will show relevant results dynamically with each keypress. Everything is working and I'm getting the data, but results are not showing on the dropdown menu

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { AppState } from '../app.state/app.state';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { UserName } from '../../model/name.model';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    import { MainService } from '../main.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-search',
      templateUrl: './search.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
    })
    export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
      searchForm: FormGroup;
    
      username: Observable<UserName[]>;
      searchTerm: string;
      searchResult: [];
      isLoading = false;
      errorMsg: string;
    
      constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private searchService: MainService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.username = store.select('username');
       }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          searchBar: ''
        });
        this.onChanges();
      }
    
      onChanges(): void {
        this.searchForm.get('searchBar').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
          this.searchService.searchingValue(val).subscribe(function(data){
            this.searchResult = data.items;
          } );
    
        });
    
      }
     
      }
```

```html
    <!-- <p>{{ username.username }}</p> -->
    <h1>Book Search</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm">
        
            <!-- <mat-form-field>
                 <input type="text" matInput formControlName="searchBar" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            </mat-form-field> -->
    
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Search" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"  formControlName="searchBar">
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                      <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
                      <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of searchResult" [value]="option">
                          <span>{{ option.volumeInfo.title }}</span>
    
                        </mat-option>
                      </ng-container>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                  </mat-form-field>
              
            
    </form>
```

Comment: do you have a stackblitz to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Total working,** example you can find out here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgluj1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**onChange() method** you have to pipe () first of all rxjs operators like filter, debounceTime, switchMap. here when text input is changed you can check valueChanges first and then in switchMap() you can fire services api calling of data.

```
onChanges(){
   this.searchForm.get('searchBar').valueChanges.pipe(
      filter( data => data.trim().length > 0 ),
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap(  (id: string) => {
         return id ? this.serachService.searchingValue(id.replace(/[\s]/g,'')) : of([]);
      })
   ).subscribe(data =>{
      this.searchResult = data as Array<{}>; 
   })
}
```

**here,**

- first pipe() operator is **filter()**, used for filter any black spaces entering by user. so, that nothing calls for api requesting.
- second pipe() operator is **debounceTime(500)**, used for waiting to stop user typing. and exactly after 5ms search string is passed on api request of switchMap()
- Third pipe() operator is **switchMap()**, used to switch to a new observable, after every valueChanges.

**search.service.ts**

```
searchingValue(value){
    return of(this.bookDetails.filter( booksName => booksName.name.replace(/[\s]/g,'').toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0 ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the created observable to the autocomplete control :

**ts**

```
...
    searchResult: Observable;

          onChanges(): void {
                this.searchResult = this.searchForm.get('searchBar').valueChanges.pipe(
                 switchMap(val => this.searchService.searchingValue(val))    
                );

              }
...
```

**html**

```
<h1>Book Search</h1>
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">

        <!-- <mat-form-field>
             <input type="text" matInput formControlName="searchBar" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        </mat-form-field> -->

            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Search" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"  formControlName="searchBar">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                  <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of searchResult | async" [value]="option">
                      <span>{{ option.volumeInfo.title }}</span>

                    </mat-option>
                  </ng-container>
                </mat-autocomplete>
              </mat-form-field>


</form>
```